# SSH Authentication Failure in source Tree

Tags: cygwin, atlassian-sourcetree

I have created SSH key (dsa) via Cygwin and placed the public Key in `github.com`. Then clone the repository and pull also work fine via `Cygwin`.

I tried to use the same key with `Source Tree`. I created the working copy by giving the same folder path and added the private key via `Tools >> Option`s as below.

But the problem is I am getting below error when I try to pull via Source Tree. What could be the possible reason.

[image]

[image: SourceTree_Error]

Comment: id_dsa is the private key. Try id_dsa.pub

Comment: @matzeri No change. same result.